# integrate $1/(x(x^2-1)^{1/2})$

Tags: integration

$$\int\frac{1}{x (x^2-1)^{1/2}} \, dx=\text{ ?}$$

Hi! I'm new to the website and I didn't learn math in English so I may make mistakes with terminology. I have given a math homework and it says the answer is $\arccos(x^{-1})+c$

I used wolframalpha to check if the answer is true but it gave me a different result. However when I tried to derivative  $\arccos(x^{-1})$ with wolfram alpha with gave me right the answer assuming x is positive. I'm a high school senior and I don't know advanced math, please try to use more simple math but all answers are welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $$\int{\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}}= \int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{1}{x})^{2}}}\frac{dx}{x^{2}}}= \int{\frac{-d(\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{1}{x})^{2}}}} = -\arcsin(\frac{1}{x}) + C$$ or if you prefer you can make the change of variable $y=\frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 0):

I would think that if $x>1$,

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sec^{-1}{x} = \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

so

$$\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} = \sec^{-1}{x}, x>1$$

Edit: Since you have so many answers, note that to say the antiderivative is $\cos^{-1}{(1/x)}$ and that it is $\sec^{-1}{x}$ is equivalent because cosine and secant are reciprocal functions. If you have the inverse trig derivatives memorized, the version I provided would be easiest.

Comment: Are you saying that $cos^{-1}(1) = sec^{-1}(1)$?

Comment: @SeanHenderson Yes, both are zero.

Answer (score 0):

Well, differentiate:

$$\left(\arccos\frac1x\right)'=\frac1{x^2}\frac1{\sqrt{1-\frac1{x^2}}}=\frac1{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

so what your homework says is correct.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: set $$t=\sqrt{x^2-1}$$ then you will get $$dx=\frac{t}{x}dt$$

Answer (score 0):

We can find , when $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}\cos^{-1}\frac 1x=\frac{d}{dx}\sec^{-1}x$, as shown here:

$$y=\sec^{-1}x$$
$$\sec y=x$$
$$\frac{d(\sec y)}{dx}=1$$
Now from differential calculus we should know that $(\sec x )'=\sec x\tan x$, so
$$\sec y \tan y \cdot y'=1$$
$$y'=\frac{1}{\sec y \tan y}$$
$$y'=\frac{1}{\sec y\sqrt{\sec^2 y-1}}$$
$$y'=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

Now using the definition of the antiderivative we find that the answer to your integral is $\boxed{\sec^{-1}x+C}$

Answer (score 0):

Well, several solutions are already given. I will add another one. It is
based on a technique called 'trigonometric
substitution'. Let $x=\sec \theta ,$ then $$dx=\sec \theta
\tan \theta d\theta $$ and $$\sqrt{x^{2}-1}=\sqrt{\sec ^{2}\theta -1}=\sqrt{%
\tan ^{2}\theta }=\tan \theta .$$ [ Here $\theta $ is such that $\tan \theta
>0$]. Note that $x=\sec \theta =\frac{1}{\cos \theta },$ then $\cos \theta =%
\frac{1}{x}$ and therefore, $$\theta =\arccos \left( \frac{1}{x}\right) .$$ By
substitution, it follows that
\begin{equation*}
\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}=\int \frac{\sec \theta \tan \theta d\theta }{%
\sec \theta \cdot \tan \theta }=\int d\theta =\theta =\arccos \left( \frac{1%
}{x}\right) +c.
\end{equation*}